# How to display texts in front of the box in Python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I created a box and a text, and I want the text to display in front of the box. But when I try to do this, I can't see it because it is behind the box.

```
import turtle

wn= turtle.Screen()

style = ("Courier", "36", "bold")

#Box -------------------------- ([Text] Box)

b1 = turtle.Turtle()
b1.color("black")
b1.shape("square")
b1.speed(0)
b1.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=10)
b1.penup()
b1.goto(-400, -150)



#Text ------------------------ "[Text]"

t1= turtle.Turtle()
t1.speed(0)
t1.color("white")
t1.ht()
t1.penup()
t1.goto(-400, -150)
t1.write("[Text]", font=style, align = "center")

#Main loop

while True:

    wn.update()
```

I checked if the codes were in the wrong order, but I didn't find anything wrong. I also tried removing `t1.ht()`, but it wasn't the problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: `shape()` is is not box on canvas but turtle's shape - and turtle is alway on top. To draw box you have to use `forward()`/`left(90)` and `fill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shape()` is used to define turtle's shape, not to draw box on canvas. And because `turtle` is always on top so text is hidden behind turtle.

To draw box you have to use `forward()`, `left()`/`right()` and `begin_fill()`/`end_fill()`

```
import turtle

# move 
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-400, -150)

# box
turtle.color('black')
turtle.begin_fill()
for x in range(2):
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

# move
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-250, -125)

# text
turtle.color("white")
turtle.write("[Text]", font=("Courier", "36", "bold"), align="center")

#turtle.goto(0, 0)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is an approach that's a hybrid between what you were trying to do and what @furas recommended.  It uses *stamping* instead of *drawing* to simplify the problem:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 36
FONT = ('Courier', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')

screen = Screen()

textbox = Turtle()
textbox.hideturtle()
textbox.color('black')
textbox.shape('square')
textbox.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=10)
textbox.penup()
textbox.goto(-300, -150)
textbox.stamp()
textbox.color('white')
textbox.goto(-300, -150 - FONT_SIZE/2)  # center vertically based on font size
textbox.write("[Text]", align='center', font=FONT)

screen.mainloop()
```

The `textbox` turtle can be reused and reshaped to draw other text boxes as well.  With a bit of thought and guesstimation, you can calculate a reasonable text box size from the font size and the text itself.

[image]

Comment: I liked the .stamp() method from the answer given by @cdlane . I did this task using the textbox stamp to make boxes and a separate pen object for writing on them afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your Screen object. You don't have to initialize it, also you don't have to update it unless you use tracer. Just delete this Screen object and change the loop at the end to

```
turtle.exitonclick()
```

to prevent closing window.